# Can a pronoun in the second sentence indicate non-subject in the first sentence?

Tags: pronouns

1. People in ABC city love a kind of green tea. It is famous for its fruity flavor.
2. People in ABC city love a kind of green tea. It is famous for its tea fields.

first one indicates "a kind of green tea."

second one indicates "ABC city."

Are such expressions appropriate?

Comment: The first is perfect. In the second, the word "it" refers to the tea, So you are saying the green tea is famous for its tea fields. You could repeat "city": "People in ABC city love a kind of green tea. The city's famous for its tea fields." Or you could say, "People in ABC city, which is famous for its tea fields, love a kind of green tea."

Comment: @OldBrixtonian Oh! It became clear for me.  Now I can write more correct.  Thank you so much!

Comment: I firmly believe that Old Brixtonian's comment is incorrect.  I'd say your second sentence is correct, and you are referring to the city, not the tea.  "it" *can* be ambiguous to which word it refers to in a sentence, but context and meaning will usually make it clear.  Here, "it" unambiguously refers to the city, as cups of green tea do not possess fields.

Comment: @RichardWinters Oh, really! I don't have enough knowledge to decide Old Brixtonian's comment is incorrect, but your opinion is precious, too. Thank you so much for the information!

Comment: Basically, the answer is yes. A pronoun can refer to a subject in a previous sentence ("**My sister** likes swimming. **She** practices every day.") or an object in a previous sentence ("My sister likes **swimming**. **It** is her favorite sport.").

Comment: @MarcInManhattan So, ABC city is not a subject nor an object, right? OK! Thank you so much! I gradually understand better.

Comment: It is a different kind of object. “Swimming” in my examples is a direct object, while “ABC City” in yours  is an object of the preposition “in”.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are supposed to understand which noun a pronoun refers to by context.

Usually it is the most recent noun mentioned, so sentence one is no problem.  It refers to "green tea"

In sentence two there is a bit of a gap between "city" and "it", and this might make it momentarily harder to understand.  But we can use the context to understand that "it" must mean "city".  There is no real ambiguity.

You can make it easier to understand by repeating "city".